# How the steps followed help me to understand

Tags: riemann-zeta

Few days before I posted one problem on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283086/on-the-determination-of-residue) in which it was asked to determine the residue. I understood almost entire but got stuck the following

Note that after step  4, in step 5 it is written that 
$$\frac{x^2}{2\zeta(2)}\frac{1}{u-1}+O(1)$$

I am unable to understand the steps. Can some one please help me to make it clear for me ?

Thank you

Comment: It's better to post self-contained questions! At least, you're more likely to get an answer that way.

Comment: Ask this question in a comment to the answer